# Listen passively to Rx Observable

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

Consider the following class:

```
public class TestRepository {

    private TestApiService apiService = new TestApiService();

    public Observable<String> fetchString() {
        return apiService.stringFromApi();
    }

    public  Observable<String> listenToFetchStringPassively() {
        // ???
    }

}
```

Calling `fetchString()` and subscribing to it will use the api service to fetch a string from the internet.

What I want to do is have another observable, that will not actively fetch something, but 'listen' passively to any items emitted by the observable returned by `fetchString()` and forwarding them.

My approach would be this:

```
public class TestRepository {

    private TestApiService apiService = new TestApiService();
    private Subscriber<? super String> passiveSubscriber;

    public Observable<String> fetchString() {
        return apiService.stringFromApi()
                .doOnNext(new Action1<String>() {
                    public void call(String s) {

                        passiveSubscriber.onNext(s);

                    }
                })
                .doOnCompleted(new Action0() {
                    public void call() {

                        passiveSubscriber.onCompleted();

                    }
                }); 
    }

    public Observable<String> listenToFetchStringPassively() {
        return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<String>() {
            public void call(Subscriber<? super String> subscriber) {

                passiveSubscriber = subscriber;

            }
        });
    }

}
```

which works, but looks quite clumsy. Is there a more elegant way of achieving this?

Comment: I don't know if I understood you correctly but I think you may need a [PublishSubject](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/subjects/PublishSubject.html)

Comment: Or `BehaviorSubject`, depending on if you want to keep the latest value and emit it to newcommers.

Comment: What about using a connectableObservable for stringFromApi. I think you can share the emissions between multiple subscribers or observables. But you will have to be careful where you place the connect() call.